# Track PropertyChanged Event

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a view with few controls like below:

```
<c:DropTargetContentControl  Content="{Binding FavoriteTool1, Mode=TwoWay}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FavoriteTemplate}" Margin="5,0"/>
<c:DropTargetContentControl  Content="{Binding FavoriteTool2, Mode=TwoWay}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FavoriteTemplate}" Margin="5,0"/>
<c:DropTargetContentControl  Content="{Binding FavoriteTool3, Mode=TwoWay}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FavoriteTemplate}" Margin="5,0"/>
```

`FavouriteTool1, FavouriteTool2, FavouriteTool3` are properties in viewmodel.

These properties raise their `PropertyChanged` event when there is any change to `DropTargetContentControl`. Also these `PropertyChanged` are raised when I set some value from ViewModel. I need to call some functions ONLY when the `PropertyChanged` is raised due to changes in `DropTargetContentControl`.

Any suggestion how can I track the propertychanged event? I do not have flexibility to change anything on View level.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, then you can just attach a handler to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event that was implemented in that class:

```
YourViewModel.PropertyChanged += YourViewModel_PropertyChanged;

...

private void YourViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.PropertyName holds the name of the changed property
}
```